# Creating model at runtime / building function out of smaller functions at runtime

Tags: python, function, machine-learning, pytorch, directed-acyclic-graphs

This problem could potentially be solved by pure Python or I missed something and there is Pytorch-y way of solving it.

**The pure Python question without ML talk:**

Consider this example graph: INPUT is a parameter and all other nodes are functions. If there are multiple inputs to a node aggregation function `agg(n1, n2, ...)` is used.
*How do I convert this graph into an executable function?*

Expected output for example graph is:
`OUTPUT = output_node(agg(n1(i), n4(agg(n2(i), n3(n2(i))))))`

The actual graph may be arbitrary, but with these constraints:

- Only one input node
- Only one output node
- Directed
- No cycles
- No dead ends
- No nodes without inputs (except the one input node)

[image: Example graph]

**The actual purpose of this question in Pytorch:**

The nodes are actually layers of neural network in Pytorch. Input is a tensor and output is a tensor. The aggregation is simple concatenation of tensors with `torch.cat()`. *I am generating a model at runtime and I need to somehow convert it into a function I can use in the `forward()` call.*

Comment: Please show your attempt (preferably in Pytorch)

Comment: Show inputs as well